# Proving Upper Bound for Two Variable Function?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, computer-science

The question is:

```
Prove (logn)^k = O(n) for every k>=1.
```

I have never encounter a problem for proving an upper bound for two variables, so I am perplexed as to how I would approach solving this.

Comment: Might there be a typo? I think that $(\log{n})^k = O(n^k)$?

Comment: No, it is O(n).

Comment: My mistake, but perhaps this might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523070/what-is-the-big-o-of-the-function-log-n2-logn

Answer (score 0):

**Misread the question, because it is (logn)^k and not log(n^k), which is what the following assumes.**

By definition of Big O:

**(logn)^k ≤ C*n, for N>No**

Using a logarithm identity,

**k*logn ≤ C*n, for N>No.**

Thus, C = k and No = 0.

**k*logn ≤ k*n for N>0**

It is obvious that for any k≥1, that the above would hold true.

q.e.d.

Comment: $\log{n^k} = k \log{n}$, but $(\log{n})^k \not = k \log{n}$.

Comment: So it depends on how the problem actually is formulated?

Comment: Yeah, I misread the question. You are correct.